Rename dataframe columns in multiple dataframes
I'm trying to rename the columns of multiple df's using a function passed to purrr::map, but am clearly doing something wrong, as I get an error. Can anyone show me how to do this?
# Create new df rows
newrow1 <-  data.frame(t(c("a", rep("", 6))))
newrow2 <-  data.frame(t(c("b", rep("", 6))))
newrow3 <-  data.frame(t(c("c", rep("", 6))))
newrow4 <-  data.frame(t(c("d", rep("", 6))))
newrow5 <-  data.frame(t(c("e", rep("", 6))))
newrow6 <-  data.frame(t(c("f", rep("", 6))))
newrow7 <-  data.frame(t(c("g", rep("", 6))))
newrow8 <-  data.frame(t(c("h", rep("", 6))))
newrow9 <-  data.frame(t(c("i", rep("", 6))))
# Function to rename dfs
changenames <- function(x) {
  names(x) <- c("row","n_1","n_2","n_3","pct_1","pct_2","pct_3")
  return(x)
}
df_names <-  paste0("newrow", 1:9)
purrr::map(df_names, changenames)


You got a mistake because you are passing a string to your changenames function and not a data frame. you can use
purrr::map(mget(df_names), changenames)

and if you would like to modify the data.frames in the Workspace, you can use:
list2env(purrr::map(mget(df_names), changenames), globalenv())

Note that for this task you don't really need a customed function. The function setNames can solve your problem:
purrr::map(mget(df_names), setNames, c("row","n_1","n_2","n_3","pct_1","pct_2","pct_3"))


With base R, try lapply() with setNames():
l = lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "newrow")),  setNames, 
           nm = c("row","n_1","n_2","n_3","pct_1","pct_2","pct_3"))

